# Fetch the value of a property passed to method as a paremeter in jQuery

Tags: jquery, object, properties, parameter-passing

I want an abstract method to read a property of a json object according to the propertyname I pass to the method as a parameter.

I think it is easier to explain on an example.

Suppose I have the following json object:

```
var coll =
[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]

function GetPropertyValue(collection, index, property_name)
{
    :
    :
}
```

where

```
GetPropertyValue(coll, 0, 'firstName');
```

returns "**John**", while

```
GetPropertyValue(coll, 0, 'lastName');
```

returns "**Doe**, and

```
GetPropertyValue(coll, 2, 'lastName');
```

returns "**Jones**"

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. You've everything. Just assemble it using the bracket notation. By the way I've made 'G' small to comply with javascript's widely accepted naming convention.

```
function getPropertyValue(collection, index, property_name) {
    return collection[index][property_name]; 
}
```

Comment: 'property_name' is a "string" and can not preceed an object as it is a certain, existing property. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user3021830 glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would extend Amit Joki's answer to include some checking to be sure the query can even return. Something like this maybe:

```
function getPropertyValue(collection, index, property_name) {
            if(collection[index].hasOwnProperty(property_name)){
                return collection[index][property_name]; 
            }else{
                //do something here id the property is not there
            }

        }
```

It is a bit more code but you have to handle these issues, even more so when you have no direct control over the object itself.